# Why does DPKG Status file get corrupted

Tags: dpkg

I have had over the past 2 weeks 3 times a problem with the `/var/lib/dpkg/status` file. I normally grab the "old" version or edit the file to clean it from corruption, but I wanted to know, what reasons exist that could make the Status file get corrupted.

Some examples are:

- Finding many `NUL` messages in it in one of the properties for each package.
- Missing a comma or a semi colon.
- Missing some parts of the properties for a package.
- Finding only `@@@` symbols in the file.
- Finding the file completely empty or with a dot inside of it.

So what scenarios exist that could corrupt this particular file. I have seeing more than 10+ ways of fixing it, but none exist that explain why it gets corrupted in the first place.

Comment: Visit : http://thepcspy.com/read/fixing-dpkg-status-corruption/ ?